# Error de compilacion en pascal

Tags: pascal

Me descargue el ide lazarus pero no me esta compilando ningun programa intente con un hola mundo y me salta el siguiente error respecto a un programa que se me abre repentinamente a la hora de ejecutar mi codigo.

```
aa.lpr(1,2) Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but "<" found
```

Me dice que es un error de sintaxis respecto al archivo que se me abre, no se como hacer para que no se me abra este.

El programa que se me abre de la nada es que dice lo siguiente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONFIG>
  <ProjectOptions>
    <Version Value="11"/>
    <PathDelim Value="\"/>
    <General>
      <SessionStorage Value="InProjectDir"/>
      <MainUnit Value="0"/>
      <Title Value="aa"/>
      <Scaled Value="True"/>
      <ResourceType Value="res"/>
      <UseXPManifest Value="True"/>
      <XPManifest>
        <DpiAware Value="True"/>
      </XPManifest>
      <Icon Value="0"/>
    </General>
    <BuildModes Count="1">
      <Item1 Name="Default" Default="True"/>
    </BuildModes>
    <PublishOptions>
      <Version Value="2"/>
      <UseFileFilters Value="True"/>
    </PublishOptions>
    <RunParams>
      <FormatVersion Value="2"/>
      <Modes Count="0"/>
    </RunParams>
    <RequiredPackages Count="1">
      <Item1>
        <PackageName Value="LCL"/>
      </Item1>
    </RequiredPackages>
    <Units Count="6">
      <Unit0>
        <Filename Value="aa.lpr"/>
        <IsPartOfProject Value="True"/>
      </Unit0>
      <Unit1>
        <Filename Value="unit1.pas"/>
        <IsPartOfProject Value="True"/>
        <ComponentName Value="Form1"/>
        <ResourceBaseClass Value="Form"/>
        <UnitName Value="Unit1"/>
      </Unit1>
      <Unit2>
        <Filename Value="unit2.pas"/>
        <IsPartOfProject Value="True"/>
        <UnitName Value="Unit2"/>
      </Unit2>
      <Unit3>
        <Filename Value="unit3.pas"/>
        <IsPartOfProject Value="True"/>
        <UnitName Value="Unit3"/>
      </Unit3>
      <Unit4>
        <Filename Value="paramata.lpi"/>
        <IsPartOfProject Value="True"/>
      </Unit4>
      <Unit5>
        <Filename Value="ejercicio1.pas"/>
        <IsPartOfProject Value="True"/>
      </Unit5>
    </Units>
  </ProjectOptions>
  <CompilerOptions>
    <Version Value="11"/>
    <PathDelim Value="\"/>
    <Target>
      <Filename Value="aa"/>
    </Target>
    <SearchPaths>
      <IncludeFiles Value="$(ProjOutDir)"/>
      <UnitOutputDirectory Value="lib\$(TargetCPU)-$(TargetOS)"/>
    </SearchPaths>
    <Linking>
      <Options>
        <Win32>
          <GraphicApplication Value="True"/>
        </Win32>
      </Options>
    </Linking>
  </CompilerOptions>
  <Debugging>
    <Exceptions Count="3">
      <Item1>
        <Name Value="EAbort"/>
      </Item1>
      <Item2>
        <Name Value="ECodetoolError"/>
      </Item2>
      <Item3>
        <Name Value="EFOpenError"/>
      </Item3>
    </Exceptions>
  </Debugging>
</CONFIG>
```

Dejo el codigo del hola mundo por las dudas:

```
    program ejercicio1;

begin
  writeln('Hola mundo');
  readln();
end.
```

......................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Por favor agrega el codigo de tu "Hola Mundo"

Comment: ahi se lo agregue

Comment: ¿ Y porqué lo llamas con esa extensión ? Creo que el `Lazarus` lo confunde con su propio archivo de proyecto (`aa.lpr` tiene pinta de ser `Lazarus PRoject`). Ponle un nombre mas normalito, como, por ejemplo, `aa.pas`.

Comment: con el .pas el error me salta igual

Comment: Que contiene unit1.pas, unit2.pas y unit3.pas?

Comment: son programas vacios que me vinieron cuando lo instale.El error que me salta es del programa ese que se abre de la nada. No se porque se abrira

Comment: Tu programa como tal es correcto y compila y se ejecuta correctamente (sintácticamente el código). Puedes revisarlo y ejecutarlo aquí. https://www.onlinegdb.com/r12NYvNYL     
Habría que ver dónde estás colocando esas líneas.

Comment: yo creo que el problema no esta en el codigo porque he intentado con otros programas que se que funcionan y me salta el mismo programa con el mismo error. El error de sintaxis se refiere al programa que se me abre repentinamente